# Convert double for loop to recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I want to convert the following `for` loop into a recursion:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= MAX; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j + i <= MAX; ++j) {
        // print i, j
    }
}
```

Output with `MAX=2`:

```
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2
1, 0
1, 1
2, 0
```

I tried the following recursion construct:

```
void g(int i, int j) {
    if (i+j > maxint) {
        return;
    }
    // print i, j
    g(i, j+1);
    g(i+1, j);
}
```

`g(0, 0)` gives me the following output:

```
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2
1, 1
1, 0
1, 1
2, 0
```

As you can see, `1, 1` is repeated. It makes sense if you look at the recursion tree. However, how to 'fix' this code?

Note: A trivial solution would be to use memoization. This is not what I'm after.

Comment: Not sure why you launch two recursions. Just do one. `g(i, j);` and before that, you change `i` and `j` accordingly. Sth like `if (j + i < MAX) j++;` and `if (j + i == MAX) { i++; j = 0;}` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the recursion for 'i' and 'j':

```java
void printRecursion(int i, int j) {
  if (i > MAX) {
    return;
  }

  if (j + i <= MAX) {
    // print i, j
    System.out.println(i + ", " + j);
    printRecursion(i, j + 1);
  }

  if (j == 0) {
    printRecursion(i + 1, 0);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2
1, 0
1, 1
2, 0
```